# MySQL IF statements usage

Tags: mysql, database

I am using the following code to attempt to create a concatenated string of days of the week.

```
DELIMETER $$
CREATE FUNCTION recurringDay(mon SMALLINT(1), tue SMALLINT(1), wed SMALLINT(1), thu SMALLINT(1), fri SMALLINT(1), sat SMALLINT(1), sun SMALLINT(1))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    DECLARE recur VARCHAR(50);
    IF mon=1 THEN SET recur = CONCAT(recur,'Monday');
    END IF;
    IF tue=1 THEN SET recur = CONCAT(recur,'Tuesday');
    END IF;
    IF wed=1 THEN SET recur = CONCAT(recur,'Wednesday');
    END IF;
    IF thu=1 THEN SET recur = CONCAT(recur,'Thursday');
    END IF;
    IF fri=1 THEN SET recur = CONCAT(recur,'Friday');
    END IF;
    IF sat=1 THEN SET recur = CONCAT(recur,'Saturday');
    END IF;
    IF sun=1 THEN SET recur = CONCAT(recur,'Sunday');
    END IF;
    RETURN recur;
  END $$
DELIMETER ;
```

The response I get is an error around the first IF statement. Am I using IF conditionals incorrectly? Can I not just have a list of them? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to spell `delimiter` correctly:

```
DELIMETER $$
```

should be:

```
DELIMITER $$
```

Comment: >_< It would be my inability to spell. Thanks.